# Identifying if a data is RSS or HTML on python

Tags: python, html, rss

Is there a function or method I could call in Python 
That would tell me if the data is RSS or HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filetypes should generally be determined out-of-band. eg. if you are fetching the file from a web server, the place to look would be the `Content-Type` header of the HTTP response. If you're fetching a local file, the filesystem would have a way of determining filetype—on Windows that'd be looking at the file extension.

If none of that is available, you'd have to resort to content sniffing. This is never wholly reliable, and RSS is particularly annoying because there are multiple incompatible versions of it, but about the best you could do would probably be:

1. Attempt to parse the content with an XML parser. If it fails, the content isn't well-formed XML so can't be RSS.
2. Look at the `document.documentElement.namespaceURI`. If it's `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml`, you've got XHTML. If it's `http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#`, you've got RSS (of one flavour).
3. If the `document.documentElement.tagName` is `rss`, you've got RSS (of a slightly different flavour).

If the file couldn't be parsed as XML, it could well be HTML (or some tag-soup approximation of it). It's conceivable it might also be broken RSS. In that case most feed tools would reject it. If you need to still detect this case you'd be reduced to looking for strings like `<html` or `<rss` or `<rdf:RSS` near the start of the file. This would be even more unreliable.

Answer (score 2):

You could always analyze it yourself to search for an `xml` tag (for RSS) or `html` tag (for HTML).

Comment: If you mean the `<?xml>` declaration, there is no guarantee there will be one in an RSS file (or in any kind of XML file).